# Repeat the same rules for different files in webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass, webpack-5

I have `webpack.config.js` file that has the same set of rules repeated for different SCSS files.

For example within the rules:

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      // in here
    ]
  }
}
```

I have a `src/styles/templates/cart.scss` file that outputs to `template.cart.css`:

```js
      {
        test: /cart\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "src/styles/templates/cart.scss")
        ],
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'template.cart.css',
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'extract-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              url: false
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: false,
              sassOptions: {
                outputStyle: 'compressed'
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

Then I have the same thing for `src/styles/templates/account.scss` into `template.account.css`:

```js
      {
        test: /account\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "src/styles/templates/account.scss")
        ],
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'template.account.css',
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'extract-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              url: false
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: false,
              sassOptions: {
                outputStyle: 'compressed'
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

This is repeated 10+ times for different files.

Is there a way to streamline this rather than repeating the same large chunk of code for each file pair?

Comment: Use a less specific `test` regex to handle all scss files with only one single rule. For example: `{ test: /\.scss$/i, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ] }`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Martin ! That would output the content of all matching files to a single output file though would it not? I need separate files unfortunately.

Comment: No, this can produce several files. You can leave out the `style-loader` and use for example the miniCssExtractPlugin (see [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#examples)) if you want to output css files. Or choose your own set of loaders as you need it. The point is: you can handle it all with a single rule which ony checks the file extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to answer this once I found the solution.

@Martin sent me in the right direction. I misunderstood the use of [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/).

The solution in this case was to include the `MiniCssExtractPlugin`:

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
```

Then use in in the rule with a more general test:

```js
      {
        test: /.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              url: false
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: false,
              sassOptions: {
                outputStyle: 'compressed'
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```